# When did 'street', 'road', etc. start being capitalised?

Tags: nouns, capitalization, toponyms

Old newspapers and books seem to very rarely capitalise (and often hyphenate) phrases like "High street", "Herbert-road", and "Trusting lane". These days, we capitalise "Street", "Road", and "Lane". When did the change come about? (Or, of course, am I wrong in my thinking?)

I am vaguely thinking it was around the 1950s or '60s.

Comment: [Here](https://books.google.com/books?id=hiN6kaF3b4YC&pg=PA65&dq=%22herbert+street%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=UdyLVeKHL4nz-AG404FI&ved=0CF4Q6AEwDDgU#v=onepage&q=%22herbert%20street%22&f=false) is a Google Books link.

Comment: I would have gone with "Drury lane" :)

Comment: A major complication in answering this question is the fact that for a number of decades in the 1600s and 1700s it was quite common to capitalize common nouns, which results in many examples of _Drury Lane_, _Aldersgate Street_, _Grub Street_, _Fleet Street_, _Downing Street_, etc., from that era.